# Error: Unknown provider: $resourceProvider <- $resource <- myservice AngularJS services

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, service, controller

I am getting this error and I tried different methods, but still I have not found any solution.
This is my code:

**services.js**

```js
angular
.module('myApp.services',[])
.service('myservice', function($resource) {

  var pendings = $resource('myUrl2', {methode: 'GET', isArray:true});
  var items; 

  var myPo='rawad al bo3bo3';
  var quantity;
  var barcode;

  return {
    getItems: function() {
      items = $resource('myUrl', {methode: 'GET', isArray:true});
```

And this is my controllers:

```js
angular
.module('myApp.controllers', [])
.controller('ReceiveCtrl', ['$scope','myservice', function ($scope,myservice) {
```

html:

```html
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>My AngularJS App</title>
    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/primeUI/prime-ui-0.9.5.css"> -->
  </head>
  <body>

    <ul class="menu">
      <li><a href="#/Receive">view1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#/Pending">view2</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div ng-view></div>

  </body>
</html>
```

In the controller I can't access the variable coming from my services... so the alert message won't work and I get this error

```
Error: Unknown provider: $resourceProvider <- $resource <- myservice
```

Answer (score 60):

You have to include `angular-resource.js` file and load `ngResource` module: `angular.module('app', ['ngResource'])`

For more details check "Installation" section inside the documentation for the `$resource` service: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource.$resource

Comment: so here i have a small problem since i am new to angular... the file angular-resource.js is present in folder angular... but how to load it? could u help me with it if u may?

Comment: just require it as regular javascript file inside index.html page ;)

Comment: well this is getting odd since am getting the same error... Error: Unknown provider: $resourceProvider <- $resource <- myservice i will edit my question and add the html file

Comment: Include from CDN: `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.3/angular-resource.js"></script>`

Answer (score 14):

The service module also require the resource.

```
 angular.module('myApp.services',[])
```

should be

```
 angular.module('myApp.services',['ngResource'])
```

and also the controller needs to know about your service-module

```
angular.module('myApp.controllers', [])
```

to

```
angular.module('myApp.controllers', ['myApp.services','myApp.filters', 'myApp.directives'])
```

and techincally, your motherModule does not require myApp.services only the myApp.controllers

```
angular.module('myApp', ['myApp.services','myApp.filters', 'myApp.directives' 'myApp.controllers']).
```

to

```
angular.module('myApp', ['myApp.controllers']).
```